# Find all pair shortestpath from no label nodes and loading for ever

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I got the dataset from my boss but nodes don't have labels. I want to find all pairs shortest path.
the dataset has about 10000 nodes. when I run code my system keeps loading I didn't get any output and error. my CPU runs 100%  more than 30 min

Please check my code is right?

```
CALL gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream({
  nodeProjection: '*',
  relationshipProjection: {
    ROAD: {
      type: 'RELATED',
      properties: 'length'
    }
  },
  relationshipWeightProperty: 'length'
})
YIELD sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
WITH sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
WHERE gds.util.isFinite(distance) = true

MATCH (source) WHERE id(source) = sourceNodeId
MATCH (target) WHERE id(target) = targetNodeId
WITH source, target, distance WHERE source <> target

RETURN source.name AS source, target.name AS target, distance
ORDER BY distance DESC, source ASC, target ASC
LIMIT 10
```

And call db.visualisation() is empty I don't why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The db schema is empty because your nodes don't have any labels.
You can add a label to your nodes and then the schema will also be available like so:

```
MATCH (n)
SET n:Node
```

The code for your all pairs shortest path is correct, it is just a very expensive algorithm. And once you have calculated all the paths, you only return the 10 shortest paths between a pair of nodes, so it might make more sense to store the results back to your graph. A big factor in algorithm speed is also the number of relationships you have.

Comment: I have 50000 nodes around 40000 relationships.  How can I add labels to all nodes? I got this dataset from my client. For my algorithm, I need a distance matrix.